# PHP-Sending the value of a variable in a link

Tags: php, hyperlink, get, send

So I have a navbar with links to different pages. I want the 'My Profile' to link to the logged in user's profile. In my user's php page, I have a GET to get the logged in user's name from the URL. So I can access that user's page by entering the correct URL. I can generate the correct user's page by also hard coding the user's name into the link as I have below, but obviously that's no good.

How can I get the link to send the value of the $userName variable?

```
<?php
$userName=$_SESSION['username'];

var_dump($userName)
    ?>


<div id="pageTop">
<div id="logo"></div>
    <nav>
<ul id="navbar">

<?php echo '<li><a href="user.php?u=admin">My Profile</a></li>'?>
```

Comment: Errrr. *use* the variable?

Comment: I've tried using it but can't figure it out.

Comment: You may try this `<li><a href="user.php?u=<?php echo $username; ?>">My Profile</a></li>`. Probably you should read the [Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/).

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php - http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php

Comment: @TheAlpha Perfect, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
<?php echo '<li><a href="user.php?u=admin">My Profile</a></li>'?>
```

Do this

```
<li><a href="user.php?u=<?=$userName?>">My Profile</a></li>
```

this part

```
<$=
```

is basically the same as

```
<$php echo
```

Also in user.php instead of the hard coding thing you're doing why don't you grab the get variable

```
$username = $_GET['u'];
```

and get the user data from the database where username is $username

In a situation where there is private data on the user's profile you will want to check against the session first, because anyone who goes and uses get in the url can see their profile without clearance.There are many other things to consider but for educational purposes this will get you on your way to doing what you want with this.